FreeBSD - Find child processes from parent pid in C
This question is specifically for freeBSD.
Is there an OS function I can call in C to get child processes from a parent's process id (pid)?
I'm looking for exactly what pgrep -P <PID> does.
I've come across getting kinfo_proc but there doesn't seem to be any mention of where any children's pids are stored.
Online all I can see is iterating over every single process to find if that process's parent pid is the one I'm searching for.
This seems wildly inefficient and I was wondering if there was any function/file I could use to get child processes from a parent by pid.
Please don't include a solution with procfs as this program is intended to run on various instances so setting up something like procfs specifically for my system won't work.

procinfo is not something you set up. It's just there unless you take steps to get rid of it.

https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-src/blob/main/bin/pkill/pkill.c

    /*
     * Retrieve the list of running processes from the kernel.
     */
    kd = kvm_openfiles(execf, coref, NULL, O_RDONLY, buf);
    if (kd == NULL)
        errx(STATUS_ERROR, "Cannot open kernel files (%s)", buf);
/*
     * Use KERN_PROC_PROC instead of KERN_PROC_ALL, since we
     * just want processes and not individual kernel threads.
     */
    if (pidfromfile >= 0)
        plist = kvm_getprocs(kd, KERN_PROC_PID, pidfromfile, &nproc);
    else
        plist = kvm_getprocs(kd, KERN_PROC_PROC, 0, &nproc);
    if (plist == NULL) {
        errx(STATUS_ERROR, "Cannot get process list (%s)",
            kvm_geterr(kd));
    }


Thanks for answering btw, although from my testing this code just gets the parent process and no children attached to it, even with using different flags in kvm_getprocs like KERN_PROC_PGRP or KERN_PROC_SESSION I can't get a reliable list of children, this is what I've done https://gist.github.com/AFreeChameleon/0d6de76b2179489c20d16e47c41016b7 my goal is to use the method recursively to get a tree of processes

ps -xd gives some clues, see the use of d switch within /usr/src/bin/ps/
